# Displaying fields from related tables in a Silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, lookup

I have a  Silverlight 4.0 application that has a normalised database. In this database i have tables for Applicants, Licences, LicenceClasses, LicenceTypes and LicenceStatuses amongst others. The last 3 mentioned tables are lookup tables linked to the Licences table through foreign key relationships.I am using RIA services with the Entity Framework for data access. The scenario i am facing is as follows. 
When i create a datagrid on my form i get all the appropriate colums with fields from the Licences table. I want to display the names from the lookup tables that are represented by the ID fields in the Licence table. I need to show for instance the LicenceStatus instead of the LicenceStatusID.

I have followed some examples about including the related collections in my domain service and making all the appropriate Include annotations in the Metadata classes. While i can correctly get this to work with one lookup field , i can't seem to find a way to include more than one look up table in my GetLicences query.

```
  public IQueryable<LearnersLicence> GetLearnersLicences()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.LearnersLicences.Include("LicenceClass");
    }
```

In the above query i can only include the LicenceClass collection and i have found no way of including the LicenceStatus collection or multiple look up collections that i need to display.
How do i go about accomplishing this

Comment: What if to create a Model with your own properties and fill a collection of these models before binding to the DataGrid.

Comment: Good idea vorrtex , i will certainly try that.

Answer (score 1):

You can include multiple tables by adding a include for each.

```
public IQueryable<LearnersLicence> GetLearnersLicences()     
{         
    return this.ObjectContext.LearnersLicences.Include("LicenceClass").Include("LicenceTypes");     
}
```